# mostra resultados em php

Tags: php, javascript, html5

Eu tenho 2 tabelas no banco um é *chamados* e a outra a *técnico*. A tabela *Técnico* possui os campos `id`, `nome` e `endereço`. Como, pelo código, mostrar o chamado para um técnico especifico?

Ex: Somente o técnico 1 poderá ver *A VISITA* quando for informado no banco do chamado o `id` dele, sem que consiga ver os outros chamados.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oi, Kleyton, você precisa fazer um join da tabela Tecnico com a tabela Chamado.

Montei um esquema simples para entendimento:

```
/* Tabela Tecnico */
CREATE TABLE TECNICO (
  COD_TECNICO int,
  TXT_NOME varchar(200),
  TXT_ENDERECO varchar(200)
);

/* Tabela Chamado */
CREATE TABLE CHAMADO(
  COD_CHAMADO int,
  COD_TECNICO int,
  DAT_CRIACAO datetime,
  TXT_DESCRICAO varchar(256)
);

/* Inclusão dos Técnicos */    

INSERT INTO TECNICO (COD_TECNICO, TXT_NOME, TXT_ENDERECO) VALUES
(1 , 'KLEYTON', 'Rua dos Bobos, 0');
INSERT INTO TECNICO (COD_TECNICO, TXT_NOME, TXT_ENDERECO) VALUES
(2 , 'OSWALDO', 'Rua dos Bobos, 1');
INSERT INTO TECNICO (COD_TECNICO, TXT_NOME, TXT_ENDERECO) VALUES
(3 , 'JOSELITO', 'Rua dos Bobos, 2');

/* Inclusão dos chamados */ 

INSERT INTO CHAMADO (COD_CHAMADO, COD_TECNICO, DAT_CRIACAO, TXT_DESCRICAO) 
VALUES (1,1,'2018-09-09','Chamado aberto sobre X');    
INSERT INTO CHAMADO (COD_CHAMADO, COD_TECNICO, DAT_CRIACAO, TXT_DESCRICAO) 
VALUES (2,1,'2018-09-10','Chamado aberto sobre Y');    
INSERT INTO CHAMADO (COD_CHAMADO, COD_TECNICO, DAT_CRIACAO, TXT_DESCRICAO) 
VALUES (3,2,'2018-09-10','Chamado aberto sobre W');    
INSERT INTO CHAMADO (COD_CHAMADO, COD_TECNICO, DAT_CRIACAO, TXT_DESCRICAO) 
VALUES (4,3,'2018-09-10','Chamado aberto sobre K');

/* Retorna todos os chamados de um tecnico */
SELECT T.TXT_NOME as NOME_DO_TECNICO,
       T.TXT_ENDERECO as ENDERECO,
       C.DAT_CRIACAO,
       C.TXT_DESCRICAO
FROM CHAMADOS C
        inner join TECNICO T
          on T.COD_TECNICO = C.COD_TECNICO
WHERE C.COD_TECNICO = <CODIGO_DO_TECNICO>
```

Espero que ajude